# How to get a session in a custom defined metric?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, metrics

I am trying to run a custom defined metric in Keras. I succeeded in that but I don't trust its results so I would like to inspect some values. Trouble is that everything is in tensors and I would like to convert them to ndarrays in order to inspect them. To convert them I must have a session to evaluate them. When I try to get a session using the Keras backend I get an error:

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Dense_1_target_1' with dtype float and shape [?,?]
>        [[Node: Dense_1_target_1 = Placeholderdtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,?], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]]

The only thing I want is to be able to print some information about the tensors: values, shape, etc.

```
from keras import backend as K

def t_zeros(Y_true, y_pred):
""" Just count # zero's in Y_true and try to print some info """
    threshold = 0.5
    true_zeros = K.less(Y_true, threshold) # element-wise True where Y_true < theshold
    true_zeros = K.cast(true_zeros, K.floatx())  # cast to 0.0 / 1.0
    n_zeros = K.sum(true_zeros)

    sess = K.get_session()
    y_t = Y_true.eval(session=sess) # <== error happens here
    print(y_t.shape)

    return n_zeros
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that tensorflow uses defered evaluation.

So you can't `print` the value in your function. You need to create a print node and hook it into the overall graph.

Something like this

```
def t_zeros(Y_true, y_pred):
""" Just count # zero's in Y_true and try to print some info """
    threshold = 0.5
    true_zeros = K.less(Y_true, threshold) # element-wise True where Y_true < theshold
    true_zeros = K.cast(true_zeros, K.floatx())  # cast to 0.0 / 1.0
    n_zeros = K.sum(true_zeros)

    return tf.Print(n_zeros, [n_zeros]) 

... 
my_metric = t_zeros(Y_true, y_pred)  # Returns the tensor, but we need to make sure it's evaluated
...
train_op = tf.group(train_op, my_metric)
```

You can hook it up to other operations if you want to, just make sure it gets evaluated.

Comment: I am aware of that and that is exactly the reason that I want to convert it to a numpy array. And that requires access to a session. That's why I would like to access the tf.Session.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using Tensorflow, you could use `tf.py_func` or its more modern version `tf.py_function` to make a call to a python function by passing whatever tensors you have, without needing a session. ([Tensorflow Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_function)).

The tensors you pass into the function are expected to be turned into `numpy` data/arrays. The only difference between `py_func` and `py_function` is that with `py_func` the Tensor is automatically turned into a `numpy` array, whereas with `py_function` it's still a Tensor and you have to manually call `.numpy()` on it.

Tensorflow will add this call to the graph execution for you.

```
from keras import backend as K
import tensorflow as tf

def t_zeros(Y_true, y_pred):
""" Just count # zero's in Y_true and try to print some info """
    threshold = 0.5
    true_zeros = K.less(Y_true, threshold) # element-wise True where Y_true < theshold
    true_zeros = K.cast(true_zeros, K.floatx())  # cast to 0.0 / 1.0
    n_zeros = K.sum(true_zeros)

    result = tf.py_function(some_function, [Y_true], [tf.float64, tf.int32]) # where the last argument
    # is an array representing the return type(s) of `some_function()`.
    # If `some_function` returns nothing, then you can do
    # tf.py_function(some_function, [Y_true], [])

    return n_zeros

def some_function(input):
    '''
    If you called this through py_func, the inputs are already numpy arrays,
    if you called through py_function, they're Tensors and you have to call
    input.numpy().
    '''
    input = input.numpy()
    print(input)
```